# Read File in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I'm a beginner in Tomcat and Servlet.I come across a problem about reading File in servlet. I have search a lot information about this problem in stackoverflow,but I haven't solved it.I hope get some help.I write the code as following:

```
URL url=getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/DataSpecification.owl");
File file=new File(url.toString());
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(file);    
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8");
```

I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:\localhost\MAGS\WEB-INF\DataSpecification.owl (File name or directory name wrong).
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

I put my file in WEB-INF directory.

I know that I can get an InputStream by using

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream()
```

But for some reasons,I nead to get a FileInputSream.

I hope to get your help!thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work (no need to use `FileInputStream`):

```
InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/DataSpecification.owl");
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```